# biblatex verbose styles and maxnames

Tags: biblatex, biber, verbose-note

Using biblatex+biber, and any of the "verbose" styles, it seems that `maxcitenames` has no effect. What I would like to achieve is to have citations using `\textcite` appear with a small number of maxnames, but have the full author list in the corresponding footnote.

Currently I use the following options:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=20,
style=verbose-note
]{biblatex}
```

```
Let's cite \textcite{A} here.
```

I thought this should generate something like the following:

> Let's cite Author et al.^1 here.
>
> ^1 Author A, Author B, and Author C "Paper title". In Journal, Year.

But instead I get this, as if I had the same large number for both `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames`. Is there a good workaround?

> Let's cite Author A,  Author B, and Author C^1 here.
>
> ^1 Author A, Author B, and Author C "Paper title". In Journal, Year.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{test-example.bib}
@article{a,
  author  = {A, Author and B, Author and C, Author},
  title   = {Paper title},
  journal = {Journal A},
  year    = {1921},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=20,
style=verbose-note
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test-example.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite \textcite{a} here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/245306) in the future so that it is easier to help. I have recreated your issue with a MWE and examined the `verbose-note.cbx` for an easy solution but could not find any with my limited knowledge. For clarity, `maxbibnames` only applies to the bibliography, the footnotes are actually `\footcite` and thus `maxcitenames` applies to them hence why they print similar numbers. Hope someone more experienced can assist, I think the solution will come from redefining `textcite:count` or `\cbx@textcite@init`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All citations obey the `maxcitenames`/`mincitenames` settings, this even includes `\fullcite` or the first citation in a footnote in a `verbose` style, which otherwise mimic the bibliography output.

We can make the full citation in the footnote obey `maxbibnames`/`minbibnames` instead by redefining the bibmacro `footcite:full`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=verbose-note,
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=20,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\defcounter{minnames}{\blx@minbibnames}%
       \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just for the example

Let's cite \textcite{companion} here.

Let's cite \textcite{sigfridsson} here.

Let's cite \textcite{companion} here.
\end{document}
```

[image: Let’s cite Goossens et al. 1 here. Let’s cite Sigfridsson and Ryde 2 here. Let’s cite Goossens et al. 3 here. 1 Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. The LaTeX Companion. 1st ed. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1994. 528 pp. 2 Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. 3 Goossens et al., see n. 1.]